# does the onPause method actually kill the activity?

Tags: java, android

There are 2 activities in my APP and I wanted to kill the first one while opening the second one.

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (position < 6) {

                    String sentence = conversation[position];

                    frame.setText(sentence + "");
                    position++;
                } else {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Scene1.this,Scene2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish():
```

I did this before , as the code shows, I added  finish() in onClick method but it doesn't work.So I searched some infomation and use this one now,this one actually stopped the music but I am not sure whether the activity is actually killed or not, because I want the first activity kill itself. If not,can someone tell me how to do it? Thanks in advance.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        bgm.release();
        wovleshowling.release();
```

Comment: Why do you want to kill it?

Comment: what do u mean it's not working ?

Comment: the music in the first activity won't stop, even the second activity was already opened. I guess I didn't actually kill the first activity.I want to find the code to kill it,which eventually will also let the music stop.

Comment: You mean your music is not stopping, it does not mean that your activity not got finished. Please press back button from second activity and verify it. If you get exit form your app, than for sure your first activity is finished.

Answer (score 0):

`finish()` actually isn't commited in the same moment it's executed, it just tells the Android OS that it can be freed whenever possible. Calling `finish()` will fire your `onDestroy()` method, probably this is what you're not seeing as you've written the `onPause()` content.

`onPause()` will be triggered, for example, if `Activity` A calls `Activity` B. This will actually put your `Activity` A in background and trigger `onPause()`, so it still remains in memory, but it could happen that the Android OS has lack of memory and it decides itself killing the `Activity` A. In this case, when ending `Activity` B, `Activity` A's `onCreate()` will be called instead of `onResume()` (which in turn will trigger `onResume()` as per the Activity's lifecycle).

Comment: I think you are correct, but your wording is unclear. For example, you say `onCreate` will be called instead of `onResume` but in fact, both will be called, onCreate will be called first. Calling `finish()` will trigger `onPause()` similarly to starting a new Activity. However finish() will also call onDestroy() and the Activity will not be re-created.

Comment: But what if I want Activity A to be killed when Activity B is opened? How do I operate it?

Comment: I updated my answer on the first of your statements, but I'm not sure about the other one...

Comment: @user3585596 Simply call `finish()` over it but don't expect `onPause()` to be fired, instead `onDestroy()` should be.

Comment: @user3585596 @nKn `finish()` will still trigger `onPause()`. `onPause()` is actually guaranteed to be called when before an Activity is destroyed or re-created. In this case, Starting a new Activity will likely trigger the `onPause()` before `finish()` will, but the result is the same. `onPause()` WILL be called.

Comment: I tried to call finish(), but it didn't work. Do i have to call it under a certain method? Because last time I called finish() under the onClick method and it didn't kill the activity

Comment: Of course `onPause()` will be called. It will always get called. `onPause()`, `onStop()` and then `onDestroy()`. That is guaranteed. The issue with the original code is that finish() is only executed after the second activity returns.

Comment: @user3585596 What do you mean by "it didn't work." Based on the code snippet you show above, it should be working in the sense that your Scene1 Activity will be destroyed. Where is the `onClick` method called from?  Are you in the context of an Activity or are you inside something else that overrides `finish()`?

Comment: @jacobhyphenated I agree when you say that if you start **another** activity, it will fire the `onPause()` on the opening `Activity`, but it doesn't fire it if you don't. I mean, `finish()` will not necessarily trigger `onPause()` per se.

Comment: @nKn no, onPauses will ALWAYS be triggered in the case of finish(). You get very few guarantees with the Android OS, but that is one of them. See http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ShuttingDown

Comment: @nKn, you also really need to familiarise yourself with [the Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not that `finish()` is not triggering `onDestroy()`. The problem you are having is that the second activity is created and takes focus with `startActivity(intent)` before `finish()` is reached.

`finish()` is only reached when the second activity returns. `onStop()` *may* be called if Android decides to free up some resources by stopping your first activity. In that case `onRestart()` and `onStart()` will get executed on activity 1's restoration before `finsh()` is hit to trigger the waterfall that starts with `onPause()` and ends in `onDestroy()`.

You should get familiar with the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Lifecycle).
[image: Android Activity Lifecycle]

As for your problem you should mute or stop your music in `onPause()` as you have shown in your question. You should let Android take care of memory management itself, it's quite good at it. No need for manually invoking `finish()` as long as you take care of the sound in `onPause()` (or wherever appropriate to your design).